# PDO bindParam not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This has been bugging for a long time, and I still can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.
In the code I want to select a few users with a comma separated string. The string will always be legit and valid.

In the first example, the one I would like to use, uses bindParam to assign the value of `$postId` to the SQL query. I have been using `bindParam()` for lots of other calls, but in this specific case, it fails.

```
$postId = "1,2,3";

$stm = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE find_in_set(userId, "?") ORDER BY id DESC');
$stm->bindParam(1, $postId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stm->execute();
$results = $stm->fetchAll();   
return print_r($results,true);
```

This code returns:

```
array (
)
```

In this other code which I really wouldn't like to use, I just pass the value of `$postId` right into the sql query.

```
$stm = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE find_in_set(userId, "'.$postId.'") ORDER BY id DESC');
$stm->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stm->execute();
$results = $stm->fetchAll();   
return print_r($results,true);
```

This code returns all the rows it is supposed to retrieve.

My question is; What is the specific problem and how can I avoid doing this again?

Comment: You're telling the bindParam to bind the value as string (also you should use bindValue but that's finesse at this point). What happens is that your query turns out to be `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE find_in_set(userId, "'1,2,3'") ORDER BY id DESC` instead of desired `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE find_in_set(userId, '1,2,3') ORDER BY id DESC`. Long story short - remove double quotes around the parameter in the first scenario.

Comment: Don't put quotes around the placeholder in your SQL statement, prepared statements handle that for you

Comment: I was going to say the same thing about above said comments, just wasn't 100% sure; makes sense.

Comment: @N.B. Oh I see, beginners mistake I guess.. But it sure helped, the query returns positive.

Comment: @Anders - it's one reason why bind variables are so much safer, they handle both escaping and quoting for you so you never forget to do either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't have quotes around the placeholder in yout query:

```
$stm = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE find_in_set(userId, ?) ORDER BY id DESC');
```

See additional [docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Although it's not directly related to the question, it's also a handy habit to get into to use named params. When you have only one param to pass, it's not too bad, but when you start getting five or so question marks in the query, it's MUCH easier to actually read if you used named params:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE find_in_set(userId, :someID) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Then you bind them as named params in your code:

```
$sth->bindParam(':someID', $postId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Thank you for well documented answer! +1
The place holders really is handy yes, and as you said, is okay for 1 or 2 values :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add the double quotes `"?"` when referencing the value

```
'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE find_in_set(userId, "?") ORDER BY id DESC'
```

Should be

```
'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE find_in_set(userId, ?) ORDER BY id DESC'
```

Comment: As mentioned in comments, beginners mistake, large codes troubles the mind, and you can't see straight.. :)